# How can I download an array of URLs synchronously to maintain their order in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm using React Native and Firebase V9. I am trying to download URLs from storage, but I'm not able to both download all the URLs in the correct order and have them load the first time I visit the screen. I know that getDownLoadURL() runs asynchronously, which is why the images get downloaded in random order each time. There is something I'm not understanding correctly.

Here are two main ways I've tried:

```
  const [memNameLogs, setMemNameLogs] = useState([]);
  const [memIDLogs, setMemIDLogs] = useState([]);
  const [memImagesLogs, setMemImagesLogs] = useState([]);
  const [memberCount, setMemberCount] = useState(0);

  const getGroupInfo = async () => {

    let memberIDs = [];
    let memberNames = [];
    let memberImages = [];

    let userGroupsRef = collection(db, "groups", groupID, "members");
      
    onSnapshot(userGroupsRef, (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
        memberIDs.push(document.id);

        onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", document.id), (snapshot) => {
          const one = snapshot.data();
          const two = one.firstName;
          const three = one.lastName;
          const four = two + ' ' + three;
          memberNames.push(four);
          console.log(memberNames);
        });

        const pathReference = ref(storage, 'userProfileImage/' + document.id);
        // Get the download URL
        getDownloadURL(pathReference)
          .then((url) => {
            memberImages.push(url);
          })
      });
      setMemberCount(memberIDs.length);
      setMemIDLogs(memberIDs);
      setMemNameLogs(memberNames);
      setMemImagesLogs(memberImages);
    })
```

and

```
  const getGroupMembers = async () => {
    let memberIDs = [];
    let memberNames = [];
    let paths = [];

    let userGroupsRef = collection(db, "groups", groupID, "members");
      
    onSnapshot(userGroupsRef, (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
        memberIDs.push(document.id)

        onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", document.id), (snapshot) => {
          const one = snapshot.data();
          const two = one.firstName;
          const three = one.lastName;
          const four = two + ' ' + three;
          memberNames.push(four);
        });

        const pathReference = ref(storage, 'userProfileImage/' + document.id);
        paths.push(pathReference);
      })
      setMemberCount(memberIDs.length);
      setMemIDLogs(memberIDs);
      setMemNameLogs(memberNames);
      setImagePathReferences(paths);

    })

    return Promise.all(imagePathReference)
  }

  const getGroupPictures = async (file) => {
    let downloadURL;
    await getDownloadURL(file)
    .then((url) => {
      downloadURL = (url);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle any errors
      if (error.code === "storage/object-not-found") {
        downloadURL = ('');
      }
    });

    return (downloadURL)
  }

  const getGroupInfo = async () => {

    const references = await getGroupMembers();
    console.log(references);
    for (let i = 0; i < memberCount; i++) {
      let file = references[i];
      const references2 = await getGroupPictures(file);
      memImagesLogs.push(references2);
    }
  };
```

Comment: You should consider not storing your properties in separate arrays that rely on order, and instead store model objects with ID, name, and image properties that you can update easily in *one* array.

Comment: Yeah for sure, I just haven't gotten around to figuring out the best way to organize, pull and store the data yet. I just want to throw something quick together for now for proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to store the download URLs in an associative array, with the file as the key.

Something like this:

```
const downloadURLs = {}; // 
const getGroupInfo = async () => {
  const references = await getGroupMembers();
  console.log(references);
  for (let i = 0; i < memberCount; i++) {
    const file = references[i];
    const downloadURL = await getGroupPictures(file);
    downloadURLs[file] = downloadURL; // 
  }
};
```

With that, the `references` array determines the order, while the `downloadURLs` object allows you to look up the download URL for each file.